# RecyclerView expandable with Navigation Drawer item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement recycler view instead of an expandable list view,so that when I click a navigation drawer menu item,t should expand.Her is my code,I don't how to implement.
activity_main.xml:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and this is Adapter

`public class ExpandableListCustomAdapter extends`RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private List<SubMenuItems> subMenuItemses_list=new ArrayList<>();


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView sample_text;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sample_text=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
    }
}

public ExpandableListCustomAdapter(List<SubMenuItems> subMenuItemses_list){
    this.subMenuItemses_list=subMenuItemses_list;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_custom_adapter,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
```

`}`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SubMenuItems subMenuItems=subMenuItemses_list.get(position);
    holder.sample_text.setText(subMenuItems.getItem1());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return subMenuItemses_list.size();
}
```

`}`

MainActivity.java

```
ExpandableListCustomAdapter expandableListCustomAdapter=new ExpandableListCustomAdapter(subMenuItemses2);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    prepareSubMenu();
    //here we configured text,images and added to a list
    recyclerView.setAdapter(expandableListCustomAdapter);
```

`private void prepareSubMenu(){`

```
    SubMenuItems subMenuItems4=new SubMenuItems("Main");
    subMenuItemses2.add(subMenuItems4);
    subMenuItems4=new SubMenuItems("Starters");
    subMenuItemses2.add(subMenuItems4);
    subMenuItems4=new SubMenuItems("Dessert");
    subMenuItemses2.add(subMenuItems4);
    expandableListCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home_id) {
        /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wait on....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));*/
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_id) {

    } else if (id == R.id.my_order_id) {

    } else if (id == R.id.about_id) {

    } else if (id == R.id.contact_id) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
```

`}`

Result is showing,that's not an issue.I need to implement this when someone click an item in Nav Drawer,and shows an expand list.Here I am using RecyclerView.Is it possible or I have to use ExpandableList ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Expandable list in your drawer try to follow [expandable-navigation-drawer](https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
    private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListData;
    private TextView mSelectedItemView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mSelectedItemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_item);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
        mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
        mExpandableListTitle = new ArrayList(mExpandableListData.keySet());

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        mExpandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, mExpandableListTitle, mExpandableListData);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
                mSelectedItemView.setText(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
                mSelectedItemView.setText(R.string.selected_item);
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                    .get(childPosition).toString();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedItem);
                mSelectedItemView.setText(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString() + " -> " + selectedItem);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean expandable recyclerview in drawer?